# React hooks reset state and run function in single onclick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reset, use-state

I was wondering I would I go about resetting my state and after resetting my state I then would run a function. What happens is I have click the button twice so we can reset the state. It is really strange. I tried using useEffect and have like a trigger on the button click and it did not work. Basically I want to reset my initial state and run a function afterwards on every button click. Any Suggestion would be welcomed.

Here is my code:

```
        function checkVinsReadyToInsert() {

        if (validArr.length <= availableVinsArr.length && errorCounter <= 0) {
         setDisableButton(false);
        } else {
         setDisableButton(true);
        }
    }


    function checkVinsLength(cb) {
        for (let x = 0; x < vinsArr.length; x++) {
        if (vinsArr[x].length > 18) {
            setErrorArr(oldErrorArr => [...oldErrorArr, vinsArr[x]]);
        } else {
            setValidArr(oldValidatedArr => [...oldValidatedArr, vinsArr[x]]);
        }
        }
        return cb();
    }


    function analyze() {

        
        setErrorArr([]);
        setValidArr([]);
        setErrorCounter(0);

        checkVinsLength(ReadyToInsert);
        }


    function ImportForm() {
        const [errorArr, setErrorArr] = useState([]);
        const [validArr, setValidArr] = useState([]);
        const [errorCounter, setErrorCounter] = useState(0);
        const [vinsTextArea, setVinsTextArea] = useState('');
        const vinsArr = vins.split('\n');
        return (
            <>  
                <textarea value={vinsTextArea} onChange={setErrorCounter}/>
                <button type = 'button' onClick="analyze">analyze</button>
            </>
        )
    }
```